# Error in SASS when trying to use @use at-rule

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I am trying to use new features in SCSS. And i get error when I use @use, @debug

Error:

```
Error in plugin "sass"
    Message:
        src/scss/style.scss
    Error: Invalid CSS after "...e-height: tokens": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$my;"
            on line 27 of src/scss/style.scss
    →→   line-height: tokens.$my;

       ---------------------^
```

Both files are in one directory

File token.scss:

```
// tokens.scss;    
$my: 32px;
```

File style.scss:

```
// style.scss
@use 'tokens';

.link {
  font-family: $font-family;
  line-height: tokens.$my;
  color: $link-color;
  display: inline;
}
```

package.json:

```
…
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "stylelint": "^13.6.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^1.1.2",
…
```

sass

```
@MacBook-Pro-Admi frontend-gulp % sass --version
1.26.8 compiled with dart2js 2.8.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@use* is [not supported](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2886) in *node-sass* yet. You have to use `@import` instead. Currently only [dart-sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) supports *@use*.

Comment: Thank you @gh05d! You solved my problem! I had to remove node-sass and sass (global). Then I was installed again sass (local) and used dart version of compiler into gulp config — sass.compiler = require("sass")